# Fragment cache not updating 30 mins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fragment cache setup to expire 30 minutes.

```
<% cache(:expires_in => 30.minutes) do %>
   <!-- table with items -->
<% end %>
```

It made the first cache but now the items in the table are being updated and it still shows the old data. Its been hours since the items have been updated. I have cleared the cache in my browser but it still uses the first cache it made.

This is the first time I've setup caching so I could be doing something wrong.

**Update**

I'm not keen on having the cache update each time an item is updated. The reason being is that each item has many `values`, item values are what is displayed on the table. Each time an item is updated the actual item record isnt update but all is values are updated. If I have the cache refresh each time a value is updated then it will re fresh the cache 10 times each time an item is updated because all that items values get updated simultaneously.

Because of this I figured updating the table every 30 mins would be fine.

Comment: Regarding "I have cleared the cache in my browser ..." -- I think the content is actually cached in `Rails.cache` and not the browser's cache.

Comment: Yea it is but i thought maybe my browser cached the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `fragment_cache` doesn't exactly.

Because rails have `method` which is called name as: `expire_fragment`

```
<% cache(key, :expires_in => set_time_here) do %>
   <!-- content -->
<% end %>

expire_fragment(key)
```

You can rewrite as:

```
def expire_items_cache
  puts "expire_items_cache"
  expire_fragment("items") 
end

<% cache("items", expires_in: 30.minutes) do %>
   <!-- table with items -->
<% end %>
```

You can refer more at [fragment_caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)

Answer (score 0):

Manual cache expiration is dead, try key based expiration where you don't supply a manual cache expiration time, the key will automatically change when the object change, since `updated_at` change so key will automatically change and new cache will get build and you don't need to worry about old Cache it's handeled well for you and swiped out whenever the needs be(Memcache), So Try this

```
<% cache([items,items.max(:updated_at)]) do %>
   <!-- table with items -->
<% end %>
```

and one more it's not cached at your browser it stays in you server cache store
[Rails Guide Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) and look for fragement caching
try watching this Railcast as well [Fragment Caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching)

Comment: Gives the error. `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`